# Multiple conditions in updateOne query in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Document in mongodb collection 'users' is

```
{
    "$oid": "5e612272bcb362513824ff9b",
    "name": "abcd",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "cart": {
        "items": [{
            "productId": {
                "$oid": "5e614367cae25319c4388288"
            },
            "quantity": {
                "$numberInt": "1"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

For a particular users._id and a productId in cart.items, I need to increase the quantity by 1

My nodejs code is

```
IncrCartItem(prodId){
    const db=getDb()
    return db
    .collection('users').
    updateOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(this._id),'this.cart.items.productId': new mongodb.ObjectId(prodId)},{$inc : {'this.cart.items.quantity':1}}) 
  }
```

Is the query right for checking multiple conditions in updateOne()??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kinda there, to "and" them all together you just keep appending them, however the field is wrong and you need to use the positional operator ($) - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```js
const filter = {
  _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(this._id),
  'cart.items.productId': new mongodb.ObjectId(prodId)
};
const update = {
  $inc : { 'this.cart.items.$.quantity': 1 }
};

IncrCartItem(prodId){
    const db=getDb()
    return db
    .collection('users').
    updateOne(filter,update) 
  }
```